# FacesMessage error rendering view

Tags: java, maven-2, jsf-2, glassfish, primefaces

I have this a when launching(clean build and run) my JavaEE web application :

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/TV/Admin3B/Monitoring/AjoutSpots.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2880)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2577)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I print my **FacesMessage** with `<p:growl />`
when I remove it and I reload the page and insert it again the problem was solved , but when I relaunch the application this bug is thrown again.
I don't have any idea about this.

Thanks

Mounir

Comment: Related: [IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in one of the latest Mojarra versions. See also [issue 2215](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2215). This will occur when the response is larger than the default response buffer and thus causes a commit of the response. However, when after that point a view or session scoped managed bean needs to be created and the session hasn't been created yet, then the session creation will fail because the response is already committed. When a session is to be created the servletcontainer namely needs to set a cookie on the response header. This isn't possible anymore when the response headers are already been sent (committed).

Until the Mojarra guys fix it so that you can upgrade, one of the workarounds is to create the session yourself with help of a `Filter` which runs right before the `FacesServlet` does its job.

Comment: Hi, Yeah it's a problem but I changed the State Saving method in client and the problem does not appear again. <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: Thanks for information Balus, hope that Mojarra fix this bug rapidly.

Comment: FYI: this issue has been fixed since Mojarra 2.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it so:
In the file with the function of my button (page.xhtml) I had bad write the ManagedProperty:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="fileSessionBean") 
... rest code...
```

I change this for:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{fileSessionBean}") 
... rest code ...
```

This work fine now,

Comment: Its working fine, thanks for it !!!!